# Where the user verification is done?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

Sorry I am new in nestJs, I'm using a sample application from github:

https://github.com/lujakob/nestjs-realworld-example-app

My question is about how to formally do verifications on users that have the right to modify a specific article. Normally, this portion of code should have a verification:

```
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Update article' })
@ApiResponse({ status: 201, description: 'The article has been successfully updated.'})
@ApiResponse({ status: 403, description: 'Forbidden.' })
@put(':slug')
async update(@param() params, @Body('article') articleData: CreateArticleDto) {
// Todo: update slug also when title gets changed
return this.articleService.update(params.slug, articleData);
}
```

So that not everybody could modify elses articles.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NestJS has the concept of Guards 
https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Guards are another type of Middleware that will be executed before your Route Handler gets invoked. Guard is only a mechanism to help you guard your routes. Underlying implementation (like Roles or Permissions) need to be implemented by you.

Comment: thank you, I know that can be implemented with guards, but I don't understand in the example I shared how it was implemented ... I don't see any guard

Comment: https://github.com/lujakob/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/user/user.module.ts 
In the example you linked, the author does not use Guards but he uses a raw Middleware and attach the middleware on `user` route in UserModule.

Comment: That portion of code only checks if the user exists and is authenticated, but doesnt check if the element he is modifying or deleting is owned by him !